# Как правильно писать "расчёт-рассылка" или "расчёт рассылки"?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Проясните: "расчёт-рассылка" или "расчёт рассылки"? (После следует список того, кому предназначена рассылка: финансовая, юридическая, банковская.)

Answer (score 2):

Справочное бюро Грамоты.ру даёт такой ответ на этот вопрос: «Предложенные вами варианты орфографически верны, но различаются по значению и грамматическим свойствам. Расчет-рассылка — это сочетание с приложением (то есть расчет, являющийся одновременно и рассылкой). Расчет рассылки — это словосочетание со связью управления, с вопросом: расчет чего?»

При этом, судя по практике письма, в терминологическом значении оба варианта всё-таки употребляют как синонимы (вопреки логике языка), однако в неравных пропорциях: из всех случаев употребления, выдаваемых гуглом, на вариант с дефисом не приходится и шести процентов, в то время как на вариант-словосочетание — более 94 %.